# twitter style scroll load for a flask stream_with_context page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I have a search page which will search through a static file and grab some information to throw on a front page. The following is how I manage the algorithm which creates the search.

```
@search.route('/')
def properties_search():
    if len(request.args) > 0:
        d = CSVReader()
        row_count = len(list(search_csv(d, request.args)))
        gen = stream_with_context(search_csv(d, request.args))
        return Response(
            stream_with_context(
                stream_template(
                    'advanced_search/results.html',
                    rows=gen
                )
            )
        )
    return render_template('advanced_search/advanced.html')

def search_csv(rows, form):
    for row in rows:
        if satisfies_all_requirements(row, form):
            yield row
```

However, when this hits the page, it will continue rendering every result without stopping.

```
<div class="results">
  {% for each in rows %}
    {# blah blah some html goes here, you get the point #}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

how would one enable infinite scrolling on this template so that it does not render every single result on the first hit?

Comment: this was quite a bit of time ago, but what I ended up doing in the long run was setting a limit on the amount of data that could be send, and used a pg-query-stream to write it to a socket that would be responded to on the client with javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a separate concept from streaming your response.  Instead, create a route that will return another chunk of data, maybe in JSON format, and use JavaScript on the client side to call this route when the page is scrolled to the bottom and insert the data appropriately.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # this page just loads the start page containing the javascript that will load more results
    # you could pre-load the first set of data so the page renders something at first
    data = get_some_data()
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)

@app.route('/more')
def more():
    # this route will only be called from JavaScript when the page is scrolled

    # read query parameters to know what data to get
    page = request.args.get('page', 1)
    per_page = request.args.get('per_page', 20)

    # get the requested set of data
    data = get_some_data(page, per_page)

    # return it as json
    return jsonify(data=format_data_appropriate_for_jsonify(data))
```