# scroll to fetch more data AJAX request

Tags: ajax, python-2.7, flask, get

So I have this simple Flask app that returns a feed of items queried from a SQL database. When you hit bottom of the page I want to fetch more data, so I am using an ajax get call to count number of divs and return 3 more divs.

flask view

```
@app.route('/more', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def more():
    start = 0
    stop = int(request.args['stop'])
    limit = stop
    return render_template('feed.html', feed = feed.query.order_by(feed.added.desc()).slice(start,stop).limit(limit).all())
```

ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var start = $(".div").length;
      var stop = start + 3;

      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
          $.get('/more', { start : 0, stop :  stop, 
                success:  window.location = '/more?start='+0+'&stop='+stop});
             }
       });
});
</script>
```

However, this will obviously cause the page to redirect and jump to the top of the page and change the url to something like `'.../more?start=0&stop=8'`. As this is normal behavior, how can I do exactly the same, but stay at the bottom of the page and keep my current URL `.../feed`? i.e do what the twitter feed, facebook feed etc does

Comment: you will need to dynamically load the newer data and pass it into the js through an ajax request to the server and append it to your html through javascript. In your case, you are reloading the entire page. see - http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/jquery-infinite-scroll-flask-bootstrap/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [twitter style scroll load for a flask stream\_with\_context page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313840/twitter-style-scroll-load-for-a-flask-stream-with-context-page)